# Abstract-group isomorphisms between linear algebraic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be linear algebraic groups over the rationals. Suppose that we know that $G(\mathbb Q)$ and $H(\mathbb Q)$ are isomorphic as abstract groups. Does it under any circumstances follow that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic as linear algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-groups?

Comment: There's a large literature on this, notably by J. Tits, in the 50s and 60s.

Comment: I guess this is true if $G$ is semisimple, one should locate the reference (possibly it might assume the absence of anisotropic factor?). It is true when $G$ is unipotent: then $H$ is unipotent and every isomorphism is algebraic (this is specific to $\mathbf{Q}$ this time). This is true if $G,H$ are split tori (just counting the 2-torsion), but I doubt about more general tori (this might in many cases provide a free abelian group of infinite countable rank?), or, for the same reason, if only $G$ is assumed to be a split torus. It might be true in general when $G$ is generated by unipotents?

Comment: You have to clarify what you mean by "algebraic groups over rationals": Do you mean "sets of rational points" in such groups? Keep in mind that, say, the rational algebraic group $SL(n)$ is just a set of algebraic equations. The set of rational points of $SL(n)$ is $SL(n, {\mathbb Q})$ is the set of rational solutions of these equations.

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes certainly OP assumed $G=\mathbb{G}_\mathbf{Q}$, $H=\mathbb{H}_\mathbf{Q}$ and asks whether the existence of an isomorphism $G\to H$ implies that of a $\mathbf{Q}$-isomorphism $\mathbb{G}\to \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @YCor, I don't think [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414289/abstract-group-isomorphisms-between-linear-algebraic-groups#comment1062326_414289) is quite certain; for example, for many people with the 'old' language, an algebraic group 'is' its set of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$-points, so "an abstract isomorphism of $\mathbb Q$-groups" might mean an abstract isomorphism of their groups of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$-points, or perhaps a $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$-equivariant such isomorphism. Without clarification, there's no way to know, so the OP should clarify.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414289/abstract-group-isomorphisms-between-linear-algebraic-groups#comment1062323_414289), isn't a reductive group whose set of rational points (I don't remember what conditions the ground field must satisfy, but $\mathbb Q$ should work) is generated by unipotent elements automatically semisimple, and maybe even automatically simply connected?

Comment: Is $G = SL_3(\mathbb{Q})$ and $H = PSL_3(\mathbb{Q})$ a counterexample?

Comment: (Previous discussion of “homomorphismes abstraites”:  [theorem of Borel and Tits](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33348/theorem-of-borel-and-tits).)

Comment: @LSpice I never said reductive

Comment: @spin no. Because $\mathrm{PSL}_3(\mathbf{Q})$, in the sense, the $\mathbf{Q}$-points of the $\mathbf{Q}$-group $\mathrm{PSL}_3$ (which to avoid ambiguity should better be called $\mathrm{PGL}_3$), is not reduced to the image of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Q})$. The cokernel of the induced map $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Q})\to\mathrm{PGL}_3(\mathbf{Q})$ is the infinite abelian group $\mathbf{Q}^*/{\mathbf{Q}^*}^3$.

Comment: Your edit did not clarify anything: To get an abstract group, you have to take your algebraic ${\mathbb Q}$-group ${\mathbb G}$ and consider its set of $K$-points for some field $K$, ${\mathbb G}(K)$. What I asked is: Which field $K$ do you take? Common options include $K={\mathbb Q}$, $K=\bar{\mathbb Q}$. When one says "affine variety over ${\mathbb Q}$," it just means an ideal of polynomials with rational coefficients. This, by itself, does not form an abstract group, so it's meaningless to talk about "isomorphism of abstract groups" regarding ${\mathbb G}$ itself.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am not very familiar with the terminology around algebraic groups, but now I see what you mean.  $G(\mathbb Q)$ and $H(\mathbb Q)$ are isomorphic as abstract groups.

Comment: Good edit, except I do not understand what "under any circumstances" means. I suspect, you simply mean "does it follow".

Comment: I think the "under any circumstances" part of the question might be meant to mean something like "Does it follow that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic as abstract groups, and, if not, what are some additional conditions that would imply that?"

Comment: Here are three non-$\mathbf{Q}$-isomorphic tori, for each of which the group of $\mathbf{Q}$-points is isomorphic to the direct product of a group of order 2 and a free abelian group of infinite countable rank: (a) the 1-dimensional split torus $\mathrm{GL}_1$ (b) the group $\mathrm{SO}_2$ (determinant 1 matrices of size 1 preserving the form $q$ — this is an anisotropic 1-dimensional torus (c) the group of similarities of $q$ — this is a 2-dimensional torus, whose $\mathbf{Q}$-points form $\mathbf{Q}[i]^*$.

Comment: @YCor: Thanks for the clarification. So then if I understand correctly, for the same question with $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}$: the groups $G = \operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $H = \operatorname{PGL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ would give a counterexample.

Comment: There is a conjecture of Borel and Tits on the "source" of abstract group homomorphisms $\rho:G(k)\to H(k')$ for linear algebraic groups defined over different infinite fields $k$ and $k'$. See this recent paper by Rapinchuk and Ruiter: https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.07351 and the references therein. The BT conjecture assumes that the subgroup of $H(k')$ generated by the image of unipotents in $G(k)$ is Zariski dense in $H(k')$, so it does not apply in the counterexamples of @YCor, which are tori.

Comment: Title of @UriyaFirst's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414289/abstract-group-isomorphisms-between-linear-algebraic-groups#comment1062472_414289):  [Rapinchuk and Ruiter - On abstract homomorphisms of some special unitary groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.07351).